# Core Plot Bar - Legend for just a few bars

Tags: ios, core-plot, legend, cptbarplot

I have one Bar Plot. This bar graph has ten bars but I just want to present the caption of only first 3 bars.

I even tried adding in an NSArray assistant the first three plot but without success.

Some help? idea? criticizes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement one of the following methods in your datasource:

```
-(NSString *)legendTitleForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot
                       recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
-(NSAttributedString *)attributedLegendTitleForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot
                                           recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

Return a title for the bar index if you want it to appear in the legend or `nil` to exclude that bar from the legend.